# Comparing 3 dates (from separate columns) and populating a 4th column with the oldest

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

Using SharePoint Online, I'm working in a list that has 3 dates - for my example date1, date2 and date3. In a 4th column I want the oldest date to show. Here is my column formatting, but all that is happening is the formula is showing up and no date. Thanks for the help!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent":"=if([$date1] <= [[$date2] && [$date1] <= [$date3], [$date1], =if([$date2]<=[$date3],[$date2],[$date3]))"
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that my three date coulmns are set up as type "Date and Time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions start with the `=` but they aren't part of the `if` statement. You're repeating it which is causing the formula to be evaluated as a literal value (outputing the formula). Try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent":"=if([$date1] <= [[$date2] && [$date1] <= [$date3], [$date1], if([$date2]<=[$date3],[$date2],[$date3]))"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Thant makes a lot of sense, but it didn't fix the problem... (I also tried removing the = from the beginning of the statement, but that didn't help either)

Comment: Wait! That works! looks like I also had an errant [